# How Can I Get Only The "Shared with me" File In Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'd like to retrieve the files under the "Shared with me" label, and only those files, to be able to get the newly shared with me files

I noticed that those have no parents, so I can't get them with a files.children request or a files.list request with a q parameter.

I don't want to retrieve all the files then check if they have parent. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the query:

```
not 'user@example.com' in owners
```

This will return any files the current user has access to, but is not an owner of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does almost the trick : i still retrieve files which are shared with me and which i put in my drive. But this does narrow down my results enough so i can check which files of this request have parents.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `sharedWithMe` parameter in combination with the query by @Steve Bazyl to get just the shared-with-me files.

```
{
  "fields": '*'
  "sharedWithMe": true,
  "q": "not 'user@example.com' in owners"
}
```

Or simply

```
{
  "fields": '*'
  "q": "sharedWithMe"
}
```

The second with a simpler query returns fewer results, which I cannot conclusively explain.